# Codeigniter config file change from model or controller

Tags: codeigniter, model, controller, config

How can we edit config file details from model or controller...? I want to change currency based on location of the user...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From Codeigniter User Guide - [Setting a Config Item](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/config.html)

with this:

```
$this->config->set_item('item_name', 'item_value');
```

you can change your config item on the fly.

Comment: But that doesn't change the file content, does it?

Comment: No it doesnt. Sorry for late response

Answer (score 1):

You can just read config files as common files like `*.txt`, then parse and change what you need. For example, you want to change value of `$config['is_admin_configured']` to `TRUE` in `config.php` File. Then Below is Example for this. You can modify it for further use.

**Example**

```
$out = '';
$pattern = '$config[\'is_admin_configured\']';
$newValue = 'TRUE';
$filename = "application/config/config.php";
echo $filename;
if (file_exists($filename)) {
  $file = fopen($filename, 'r+');
  while (!feof($file)) {
    $line = fgets($file);
    if (strpos($line, $pattern) !== false) {
      $out .= $pattern . "=" .$newValue .";";
      echo $newValue;
    } else {
      $out .= $line;
    }
  }
  file_put_contents($filename, $out);
  fclose($file);
} else {
  echo ' File not found';
}
```